# uninitialized constant Model::AlgoliaSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I have an issue including Algolia module in my rails app 
I have included gem "algoliasearch-rails", ran bundle install and added in config/initializers an algoliasearch.rb file with api id and key

```
#model.rb

include AlgoliaSearch

algoliasearch do
 attribute :name, :description, :content, :is_public => true
end
```

Comment: Did you actually put those lines inside a model class? I mean having a model called `Model` is confusing :)

Comment: this is a generic name :)

Comment: So did you restart the server to be sure it wasn't "just" a gem loading issue?

Comment: Yes I did and that was it. thanks hugo & redox

Answer (score 3):

I think you should restart your rails server ;)